# C# equivalent of std::sort and std::unique

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, unique

I have a list of integers in C#. I wish to remove duplicates. 
In C++ I would run it through the std::sort and then std::unique algorithms for a very efficient way of obtaining the unique list.

What's the best way to do the same thing in C#? In other words, I'm looking for a more elegant way to do the following code:

```
    private static int[] unique(int[] ids)
    {
        IDictionary<int, object> d = new Dictionary<int, object>();
        foreach(int i in ids)
            d[i] = null;

        int[] results = new int[d.Count];
        int j = 0;
        foreach(int id in d.Keys)
            results[j++] = id;

        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What version of .NET are you using?

In .NET 3.5 that's as simple as calling the [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) extension method and then [ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) if you really need an array again.

For example:

```
int[] x = new[] { 1, 4, 23, 4, 1 };
int[] distinct = x.Distinct().ToArray();
// distinct is now { 1, 4, 23 } (but not necessarily in that order)
```

Answer (score 3):

if you considering STL methods as "very efficient", so use following:

```
       var vals = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3 };
       vals.Sort();
       var uniques = new HashSet<int>(vals);
```

For 2.0 equivalent

```
List<int> vals = new List<int>();
vals.Add(1);
vals.Add(2);
vals.Add(3);
vals.Add(2);
...
vals.Sort();
List<int> uniques = new List<int>();
vals.ForEach(delegate(int v) {
 if (!uniques.Contains(v)) uniques.Add(v);
});
```

Comment: I don't think there's much benefit from the Sort - as I understand it, a HashSet is in no particular order. Plus it is .NET 3.5 (the OP only has .NET 2.0)

Answer (score 1):

Even with .NET 2.0, you could get the same with [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx). This will be easier to use with C# 3.0 (even with .NET 2.0), but should be usable with C# 2.0 and .NET 2.0 - you'd simply have to use Enumerable.Distinct(x) rather than x.Distinct();

Of course, ultimately these are just pre-wrapped versions of the code you posted earlier (give-or-take things like iterator blocks), so you could just push that code into a utility class and (re)use it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Alas I only have .NET 2.0 to work with

Answer (score 0):

On a half-way related note, C# has a [System.Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort(VS.80).aspx) static method that you can use to sort real arrays without using a collection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how big your collection is, but if you aren't dealing with thousands of integers this might be good enough:

```
public IEnumerable<int> unique(int[] ids)
{
    List<int> l = new List<int>();
    foreach (int id in ids)
    {
        if (!l.Contains(id))
        {
            l.Add(id);
            yield return id;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static List<T> GetUnique<T>(List<T> list) where T : IEquatable<T>
  {
     list.Sort();
     int count = list.Count;
     List<T> unique = new List<T>(count);
     T last = default(T);
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
        T val = list[i];
        if (i != 0 && last.Equals(val)) continue;
        last = val;
        unique.Add(val);
     }
     return unique;
  }
```